# Is there some django app to manage followers and followings?

Tags: python, django

I would like to manage users connections by followers and followings like twitter and other social media sites. Is there some app which already do this?

Comment: Don't know of any, but this is something fairly easy to write.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [django-relationships](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-relationships) is the one you are looking for.